# How to implement the timestamp scroll panel like latest FriendCaster app?

Tags: android, scroll

The recent update of FriendCaster brings the timestamp scroll panel as shown in the screenshot. I would like to build a similar one, but anyone can tell how to start?

The screenshot can be found in here:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/screenshot2012040810401.png/

Comment: the scroll panel that shows the timestamp I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ScrollBarPanel](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-ScrollBarPanel) on GitHub by Chris Banes. Supports custom View as scrollbar panel.

[An explanation](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=556) by Cyril Mottier on how to implement a scrollbar panel by extending ListView.